# Proper RESTful API method to modify one field for a record?

Tags: api, rest

Let's say my RESTful API deals with files and folders. With it, I can create and edit both files and folders.

A file can belong to a folder. So let's say I want to move a file to a different folder. Which would be most appropriate, according to spec and/or what is most common?

1. POST to /file/:id, sending the new folder's id, changing the value
   for just folder_id, keeping all other attributes untouched. The API
   method only updates folder_id.
2. POST to /file/:id/location, sending
   the new folder's id.

Comment: Why the downvote? How about an explanation, please? Or, perhaps a suggestion on how to better ask this question? Let's not be Nazis, people.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a straightforward answer but I guess the question I would ask myself is: should the *move file* action be more appropriate for a file resource or a folder resource to handle. I wouldn't worry too much about the URI structure until I had an answer to the question.

The move action touches three resources; the file, the original folder and the destination folder. A client would need to know at least the file URI & the destination folder URI since the original folder can be inferred. I can see a case being made for both approaches. The file resource representation (the contents of the POST) could indicate a new destination folder as a value which is assumed to empty if no move is required. A folder resource could assume that a file representation contained in a POST implies moving that file to the folder. Whichever approach makes the most sense for your business process is the one I would go with.